# How do I select the second last word from each string in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a list of strings like:

```
foo = ["asdfas ad sfa", "asdfa dfas fasd", "adf adfasd sdfasf adfdf"];
```

Now I want a mapping that maps this array into a list of the second last word of each string:

```
bar = ["ad", "dfas", "sdfasf"];
```

I know I can find them by using the regex `/(\w+)\s\w+$/`, but then how do I use the found result to perform the mapping?

Comment: You mean like `jQuery.map()`?

Comment: [map reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks. So `bar = foo.map(function(d){return d.replace(/.*\s(\w+)\s\w+$/,"$1")})`, is that what you guys would do?

Comment: i guess i would, yes.

Comment: The problem with the regex is that if there's less than 2 words, it'll leave the one word unchanged. That may be what you want, but there's really three possible behaviors here (return `''`, drop from array, or leave unchanged), and we don't know what you're expecting in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to use regex replacement like

```
bar = foo.map(function(d){return d.replace(/^.*\s(\w+)\s\w+$/,"$1")});
```

**Update:** After reading the comment below, I think this one might be better:

```
bar = foo.map(function(d){return d.match(/(\w+)\s\w+$/)[1]});
```

It throws error when there's no second-last word, which satisfies my need. And of course if you want it to just leave the string unchanged when no second-last word found then try this:

```
bar = foo.map(function(d){return d.replace(/.*?(\w+)\s\w+$/,"$1")});
```

Comment: If there's less than two (or three) words, this may not work as expected (depending on what's expected). At the very least, you should account for the possibility that the second last work is also the first - and allow `(\s|^)` before it.

Comment: I'd suggest this regex: `/(^|\s)(\w+)\s+\w+\s*$/`, and replace with `"$2"`. It will work with 2-word strings, and allows for extra spaces that may have been accidently inserted. Keep in mind though that 1-word strings will be unchanged.

Comment: @jcsanyi what about `return d.split(/\W+/g).slice(-2).shift()` ?

Comment: @rab That's another possible solution, as long as the edge cases are considered - what happens if there's whitespace at the end of the string (without looking it up, I don't know offhand what `split()` will do in that case), and what happens if there's less than 2 elements?

Comment: @jcsanyi try this in console `[ "asdfas ad sfa", "asdfa dfas fasd", "adf adfasd sdfmmasf adfdf", "one two", "onlyone","" ]
  .map( function ( d ){
      return d.split(/\W+/g).slice(-2).shift() 
});`

Comment: @rab That looks ok to me. I'd recommend posting it as a new answer - let it be voted up/down independently from your first answer.

Comment: @jcsanyi: Why the first parenthesis?

Comment: The `(^|\s)` will match either the start of the string, or a whitespace character.

Answer (score 2):

that's right, **map** is what you need

```
foo = ["asdfas ad sfa", "asdfa dfas", "adf adfasd sdfasf adfdf"];

foo.map(function(str) {
    var words = str.split(" "), total = words.length;
    if (total>2) this.push(words[total-2]);;
}, bar=[]);
alert(bar);
```

forgot [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/GEynz/) again

[new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/GEynz/1/)
EDIT: as @jcsanyi mentioned my previous code returned empty elements when string contains less than 3 words, so I found a solution and modified it again

foo is still global (it's not a bug) and second element now has only two words to check

[very new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/GEynz/2/)

Comment: Thanks. Yours and rab's both get the correct result. But I still think my answer is shorter and easier to generalize since mine only involves regex.

Comment: You should have a check for words.length<2.

Comment: @trVoldemort You are welcome, your answer is really shorter, but I don't think easier to understand. Anyway **luk2302** was the 1st one who suggested to use map

Comment: @SubirKumarSao you're right (though he didn't ask to do it), updated code and demo

Comment: ...and what happens if you don't return anything? Does that imply that the final array will contain an empty element?

Comment: @jcsanyi yep, but I'm sure there's the way to avoid empty elements later in the code

Comment: Some commentary to that effect in the answer might be appropriate. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this . I used JavaScript 1.8 Array`reduce` method

```
[
 "asdfas ad sfa", 
 "asdfa dfas fasd", 
 "adf adfasd sdfasf adfdf"
].reduce( function ( m , r ){
    var splitted = r.split(/\W+/g);
    if ( splitted.length > 1 ){
        m.push( splitted[splitted.length-2] );
    }
    return m;
},[]);
```

Comment: Why would you use `reduce` instead of `map`?

Comment: This also returns the second word, not the second-last.

Comment: @jcsanyi suppose `[
 "asdfas ad sfa", 
 "asdfa dfas fasd", 
 "adf adfasd sdfasf adfdf",
 "one two",
 "onlyone"
]` like array .. I like to ommit `onlyone` case

Comment: @jcsanyi uff .. I read question quickly  ..I corrected it to second-last .. thanks for noticing it

Comment: That makes sense (RE using `reduce`), but it's undefined by the OP which behavior he wants, and I think it deserves at least some commentary in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
bar = foo.map(function(el){
   return el.match(/^.*?(\w+)\s\w+$/)[1]; 
});
```

or with jquery

```
bar = $.map(foo, function(el, i){
   return el.match(/^.*?(\w+)\s\w+$/)[1]; 
});
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but I suspect it's because this question doesn't say anything about jQuery, and your answer assumes it's available without even mentioning it.

Comment: oh, my fault, add a mention of jquery.

Answer (score -4):

Try This. Get the Second Last Character From string..

> ```
> var str = "HELLO WORLD";
> var n = str.charAt(str.length-2);
>
> Result is: D
> ```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Please read the question again.